# TYPO3 T3Jquery returns an error in FireBug

Tags: jquery, typo3

When using T3Jquery, I get an error in FireBug

TypeError: $(...).on is not a function

It is the same whether I check noconflict or not.

Versions in use: jQuery 1.6.4 / UI 1.8.24 / Tools 1.2.7
TYPO3 4.7

Would you like to see the whole .js file?

Answer (score 1):

this is not related to TYPO3.
the .on() function is available starting from version 1.7
https://api.jquery.com/on/

So you need to update your jquery version